# how to efficiently append content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, performance, append

I am using JQuery to append large amounts of text inside a tag. I find the more text currently within the tag the slower appending is, and for large amounts of text it is too slow.

Is there a more efficient way to append text? Such as for instance creating dummy child tags and setting the content of them rather than appending to the parent?

Comment: are you certain the bottleneck is the actual DOM manipulation and not to time to manufacture the content you're inserting?

Comment: yep - I tested with and without appending

Comment: Is the content in a table (either directly in a TD or indirectly somewhere up the parent chain), or other non-fixed-size element? Every time you manipulate the dom, a recalculation of positioning is required. The effect is more noticeable in tables and elements without fixed sizes.

Comment: it is all DIV structured, but that is an interesting idea. If correct then there is not really a way around this delay...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/writing-efficient-javascript) and this one too: [jQuery Anti-Patterns](http://paulirish.com/perf/)
And in general:

- do not .append() in loop
- do not append directly into DOM
- build a string and than append it or use DocumentFragment
- do not append directly into DOM

Comment: What do you mean by "do not append directly into DOM"? At some point you need to append your stuff into DOM.

Comment: That was about using DocumentFragment. Or build string and attach it. TL;DR; build something and append to DOM as a last step.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DOM DocumentFragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) to append a bunch a node, and  take a look on Nicholas Zakas presentation in slideshare "writing-efficient-javascript"

Answer (score 1):

As I have been testing my site, I have noticed that `.innerHTML` is far quicker than jQuery's append methods. This is deprecated though and support may dwindle and die in future browsers. That said the `bgcolor` attribute still works and I remember being told that was being deprecated about a decade ago. Don't append scripts with the html fragment either as they need eval'ing (jQuery appears to do this automatically leading to slow times whereas with `innerHTML` you have to do it manually if needed). Eval is dead slow don't use it if possible. Again as previously mentioned joining an array is more efficient than string concatenation. Use variables to point to DOM nodes (i.e. `var this =  document.getElementById("YourDomNode")` then work with `this` where needed instead of repeating the `document.getElementById` statement). Declaring variables outside of a function allows them to be accessible from any function. Please note this is client side script so the variable value is a unique reference for each user. Doing that highly repeated strings can reduce file sizes depending what your doing. If you absolutely have to load in your JavaScript inline as part of your html fragments try this:

```
/* Call this section after appending to the dom with innerHTML */
var f = function() {runScripts(document.getElementById('newDOM_Section'));};
setTimeout(f,1);

/* Stick the following in your main .js file */
var stringScript
var f
function runScripts(element) {
    var scripts = element.getElementsByTagName("script"); 
    var intScriptsCount = scripts.length
        for (var i = 0; i < intScriptsCount; i++) { 
        stringScript = scripts[i].text
            setTimeout(stringScript, 1); 
        }

}
```

The above code will make the DOM changes visible before all the scripts are eval'd. This isn't multi-threading though so be careful of its use. Far better to use attributes for event handlers (onclick, onchange etc.)

Finally before manipulating an element in the dom set the style to display:none, manipulate it then set the style back to display:inline (inline is default for some common elements) or wahtever it was previously.

This is just a quick mental dump of some tactics ive used so any input / derision of bad practice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending multiple times, store each string in array and join the array when you append it to.

Comment: I want to give the user feedback about what is happening, so it is important for me to append content when available