# Load long form HTML fast on IOS7 device

Tags: javascript, html, ios7, ipad

I have a list of more than 300 questions which I am calling using AJAX requests of YUI.But the problem is it take lot of time to paint whole list on Ipad using IOS 7 OS.

Any idea which I can implement to load form fast on Ipad.

I removed Box-Shadow and all transition but it takes more than 3 sec from Desktop Browser.

Comment: Is it the download or the rendering that takes time?

Comment: @Serge- Rendering takes time

Comment: You could try setting style="display: none" on the body tag. Wait untile all the ajax is done then make the body's display visible again.

Comment: @Serge It sounds like a hack, I want to load my forms fast on Ipad.

Comment: The problem most likely comes from the browser trying to compute everything related to layout (CSS) everytime you modify the dom tree in a whole javascript call. So, you could try (I'm not sur of anything) to ease the workload by making the body non visible before it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the way you are rendering the content is to expensive.

Consolidate your append/render statements into one request.

[Take a look at this thread for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130452/how-to-efficiently-append-content-with-jquery)

Comment: Ajax Request is not the issue.Rendering takes times

Comment: @Arpit Can you post a code snippet of the append/render? If you want the content at once, there may be a more efficient way to write it.

If you are okey with the content loading as the user starts filling out the form, there are ways to continue rendering content to the end of the form while the user can access the top.